# how does setOnKeyListener work in this code?

Tags: android

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                        todoItems.add(0,myEditText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        myEditText.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                        return false;

                }
```

Can somebody please break this chunk of code down for me, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the setOnKeyListener method.

Comment: What are you not understanding? This is quite basic Java...

Comment: I've looked for the syntax of the setOnKeyListener method and couldn't find any official documentation explaining the parameters

Comment: The parameter is just an `OnKeyListener`. Let me put this in the form of an answer...

Comment: Did you look [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you don't quite understand anonymous classes.

First, the `setOnKeyListener` accepts an `OnKeyListener` object. You could create a new class that implemented this interface and then instantiate it:

```
class MyKeyListener implements OnKeyListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // ...
    }
}

// On your other method:
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
```

I hope that is clear, because that's pretty much everything you do in Java.

However, Java allows you to avoid defining another class by defining *anonymous classes*. To do it, you just perform a `new` on the base class or interface you want (`OnKeyListener`) and then add a *class body*, as if you were defining it:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

This last piece of code is what you have there.

Comment: thank you, I will look into anonymous classes.  I've only just finished Head First Java and I didn't see anything about anonymous classes in there, thank you.

Comment: My rep is not high enough to upvote (I tried), looking how to accept now